# Detection issue of 4.2 BLE device with two differents iPhone

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating a BLE device with the RN4020 module (microchip).
My problem is that the device is visible with a iPhone 8 but not with the iPhone X.

The module is well configured for iPhone with the microchip recommendations and into advertise mode :

SR,24004000  (advertise mode compatible ios)

R,1 (reboot)

The BLE versions of the iPhone 8 and X is the same and the ios version too (12.1).
To discover the BLE network I am using the tool of microchip.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: This is quite bizarre and it shouldn't happen. Can you try restarting Bluetooth and restarting all devices? You can also go to Settings->Bluetooth on the iPhone X and ensure that the RN4020 device is forgotten from the list of bonded devices, just in case.

Comment: Note that iOS caches BLE information of known devices. So if your BLE device changed (new characteristcs or so) the iPhone may not recognize until you reset your netweork settings.

Comment: Hello, it is an issue with the RN4020 firmware which is too old. Thank you